# Getting Header Values in WebApi 2 Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What is the correct way to access a header value in a WebApi2 controller?   I have method that looks like this:

```
    [Route(Name ="Stuff")]
    public SysDataTablePager Get(string sEcho, int iDisplayStart)
```

It returns paged json data to a jquery DataTable.

I am trying to this to get the search value.

```
var nameFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_1"]);
```

But I am getting this error:

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage'

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
var nameFilter= string.Empty;
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("sSearch_1", out headerValues))
{
    nameFilter = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Headers is a collection inside the Request object. You need to access it how you would access a member from a collection. If this worked for you,please accept it as answer

Comment: Or you can use `[FromHeader]` on your action parameter, which will extract it directly from you request header automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Using **ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core)** for a web api project.

Try this

```
//check the header
StringValues headerValues;
var nameFilter = string.Empty;
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Custom-Token", out headerValues)) {
  //validate the token
  nameFilter = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}
```